# SMS manager in Android

Tags: android

I am assigned a project in which I have to send an SMS message from Android SDK automatically.
Can anybody help me in this concern?

Comment: What have you done so far? You don't expect people here to come up with the complete project for you, do you?

Comment: @user please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Your asking the same question over and over won't change the fact that your questions aren't that clear.  I'd suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to this code, This may help you.

```
//Import this Header Files
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;

// call this send sms function when clicking a Button..
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
  Log.v("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
  Log.v("MEssage", message);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SendSMS.class), 0);
  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}
```

Comment: For More Info: Refer this url http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find something here: http://www.google.de/search?q=android+send+sms

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android is my first hit and provides a lot of information.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void sendSMS()
{     
    String phoneNumber = "tel:9732000689";
    String message = "Hiii..I have reached to inbox!!!";  

    System.out.println("***in sendSms****");

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, CopyOfTimerWeb.class), 0);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null); 

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
        "Message has been send to"+phoneNumber, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```