# Want to develop an app that can automatically respond to received sms

Tags: java, android, sms, response

want to develop an app that can automatically respond to a received text, include my location using gps/google maps in the returned message, and read out the received message using text to speech.

My first concern (what this question relates too!) is figuring out howto automatically reply to sms messages received.  I have built a basic GUI and menu option.  There is an EditText field that uses shared_preferences to remember the string so far.

How do I go about adding this string to an sms message, and making the messege send to whomever just texted me?  I have a decent understanding of java but I havn't been about to find any clear examples and an a bit confused.
Any help would be great!
Thanks

(Basically a java oracle version of the app inventor application "NoTextWhileDriving2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an android specific solution you can use the [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) class. Here is some example code taken from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995541/sms-manager-in-android) that deals with sending an sms message from an android application.

Have a look at [SmsMessagingDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessagingDemo.html) from the android development API demo page. Below is a snippet of the sending code.

```
 // Watch for send button clicks and send text messages.
    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sms_send_message);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(recipientTextEdit.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(SmsMessagingDemo.this, "Please enter a message recipient.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(contentTextEdit.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(SmsMessagingDemo.this, "Please enter a message body.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            recipientTextEdit.setEnabled(false);
            contentTextEdit.setEnabled(false);

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

            List<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(contentTextEdit.getText().toString());

            String recipient = recipientTextEdit.getText().toString();
            for (String message : messages) {
                sms.sendTextMessage(recipient, null, message, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        SmsMessagingDemo.this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT), 0), null);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem relevant to Android development? I found a link that looks like it could help though, can post here unfortunately.

Comment: what about SmsManager in the Andriod API?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Comment: Yeah, I know about that.  Read about it alright, was hoping for an example.  Iv'e been trying stuff non-stop since I asked this question.  :(  Trying to come up with stuff myself, and use other peoples code - to no avail.

Comment: This code is depreciated I spent hours playing with it before I realized it wasn't going to work :\

Comment: That's my fault. Actually android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager is deprecated and is replaced by android.telephony.SmsManager which I fixed above.

Comment: Hey xmpty, I managed to get the app to read out received messages automatically & print the message to the screen within the app itself. Ive done this using two classes (one contains the text to speech stuff, the other is the java code for showing the message) I'm unsure howto move forward with responding too the message?  The code above looks confusing and I wouldn't know where to put it :\ also, I obviously dont need a send button etc... it should just happen automatically like the text to speech I have working!

Comment: Tried playing with this code actually, compiled fine but crashed when a message came in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a BroadcastReceiver for receiving of SMS messages. Very nicely described in [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html).

There is also an open source application working with SMS on code.google.com [android-smspopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/).

Comment: Checked out that smspopup source code.  Very interesting stuff, I have learned alot of snippets but unfortunately not the kind of stuff that's helpful at the moment.  Been trying to implement code I found and been playing around alot but cant seem to get anything going.