# How to send message using back button

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

In Android, I am creating voice to text app in which I want to send message using back key of cell phone. I did this in onBackPressed() method. When I press back button, it shows "Your message sent successfully", but actually does not send. Here is my code. Please help me. How I can do it?

```
public void onBackPressed() {
try {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Message Sent Successfully",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Sending fail, Please try again!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}

super.onBackPressed();

}
```

I toast phoneNo and sms it show but don't know what is the fault in this code?

Comment: Do you have <uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> in the manifest?

Comment: Yes i have permissions

Comment: All I can suggest then is using a pending intent in the 4th parameter which will give you a result code (as already suggested by Volodymyr) although that may not tell you much. Have you checked that you can send an SMS to that number using the phones native SMS application?

Answer (score 2):

sorry, can't comment your post, so I write this like an answer.

are you tried to use listener: [check this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendDataMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20short,%20byte%5B%5D,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)?

One of params. is:

> sentIntent - if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the
>   message is successfully sent, or failed. The result code will be
>   Activity.RESULT_OK for success.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995802/2702648)
HTH;